# Help in understanding this derivation of Lagrange Equations in Non-Holonomic case

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Whittaker, Analytical dynamics pg 215

[image]

I don't understand how we get the final equations relating $Q_r$ with $\lambda$ given the conditions above?

Comment: It is a direct application of $ker(A)^\perp= ran(A^t)$, no?

Comment: Thank you. Umm let me revise some linear algebra. If you could write that as an answer it would be great as well. :)

Comment: No, I took a mistake: the matrices here are n x m and not n x n here. I cancelled my proof for this reason. However the generalization of what I had in my mind is in @Qmechanic's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted text  says that the vector ${\bf Q}$ with components $Q_r$ is perpendicular to all vectors ${\bf dq}$ with components $dq_r$ that are themselves perpendicular to all vectors ${\bf A}_k$ whose  components are  $A_{rk}$. But for a finite dimensional vector space $V$ we have $(V^\perp)^\perp =V$. Thus  ${\bf Q}$ lies in the vector space  spanned by the ${\bf A}_k$, so there exist $\lambda$'s such that
$$
{\bf Q}= \lambda_1 {\bf A}_1+\lambda_2 {\bf A}_2+\ldots
$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact in linear algebra that if $V$ is an $n$-dimensional [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), and $$Q, A_1, \ldots, A_m \in V^{\ast}$$ are elements in the [dual vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space), then
$$ {\rm ker}(Q) ~\supseteq~ \bigcap_{k=1}^m {\rm ker}(A_k) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad Q~\in~ {\rm span}(A_1, \ldots,A_m).$$
The proof is simpler if we define an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ in the vector space $V$, cf. mike stone's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/782009/2451).

Comment: Thank you so much